# What does “on non-bad debt and open balance accounts” mean here?

Tags: banking, bank-account

This sentence is from a policy of an organization I found on a leaflet. Can anybody please explain or paraphrase it for me? "on...debt" and "open balance accounts" are confusing me.

"If the patient is approved for financial assistance their coverage is valid for 240 days prior on non-bad debt and open balance accounts and 240 days post their application signature date."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Non-bad debt" is debt that is not seriously delinquent, still has the prospect of being paid, and has not been written off by the creditor. An "open balance account" is one that has a nonzero amount owed (has not been fully paid off). The quote seems to describe a program to help people with severe expenses due to a recent medical event. It is offering to help in some way with medical debts incurred not over the patient's entire lifetime, but within a window of time before and after the application. And it is limited to amounts that the patient is actually "on the hook for".